# Any difference among Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() and Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)

Tags: java

I was wondering, what is the difference among [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) and [Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29)

The below is picked from javadoc

> Unlike the otherwise equivalent
>   newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned
>   executor is guaranteed not to be
>   reconfigurable to use additional
>   threads.

I try the following code below, seems no difference.

```
package javaapplication5;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author yan-cheng.cheok
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        //ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        threadExecutor.submit(new BadTask());
        threadExecutor.submit(new Task());      
    }

    class BadTask implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    class Task implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println("[LIVE]");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Most probably something wrong with my understanding :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like it says:

> Unlike the otherwise equivalent newFixedThreadPool(1) the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads.

The difference is (only) that the SingleThreadExecutor cannot have his thread size adjusted later on, which you can do with a FixedThreadExecutor by calling [ThreadPoolExecutor#setCorePoolSize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setCorePoolSize%28int%29) (needs a cast first).

Comment: But, how do you adjust the thread size for newFixedThreadPool(1) ?

Comment: ((ThreadPoolExecutor)newFixedThreadPool(1)).setCorePoolSize(3);